# Sending private/inbox message to @facebook.com through graph api

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

If there is a way to send private message to a friend via sending him mail to @facbook.com with his user id?
 If there is please provide the permission required and the http params required for sending it

Comment: Sending an email does not require any special permission; and there is no API method for that, since it is just that, an email.

Comment: IF i can send it through some kind of HTTP request ? I just want an alert view popup that can send my message to facebook friend.  I can post on his wall through http request but not a message.

Comment: You won’t be able to post to a friend’s wall any more via API come next February. Why don’t you just use the Feed and the Send dialog – that’s what they are for. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: Well I am only 1 month old in the IOS development so I thought it would be good to start with the graph API and then go to FacebookSDK and rest. by the way I checked the url and found this line ""https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&
name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&
link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response"" on the link "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/"   HOW can i make something like that for a mobile app